# Dismount doesn't work in DoxBox command line

Tags: c#, process

I'm work with doxbox from my c# app and try to dismount specific disk. It doesn't work but `dismount /all` works perfectly. I used `/dismount K:` and `/dismount K` but it didn't work. What can be a problem?
Here is my code

```
            Process proc = new Process();
            ProcessStartInfo startinfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            startinfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            startinfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\DoxBox";
            startinfo.FileName = "DoxBox.exe";
            string strComm = "/dismount K";
            startinfo.Arguments = strComm;
            proc.StartInfo = startinfo;
            proc.Start();
```

Comment: "but it didn't work" doesn't work as a problem statement.

Comment: I've figured out that /dismount doesn't work from shell either. So, maybe, it doesn't work at all(